# IOS - Creating & Using Interval Specific Timers

Tags: ios, timer, fixed, intervals, schedule

I am a newbie IOS developer, but I have a good amount of experience in Android development. My question is regarding the creating and use of interval specific timers.

In android I could easily make a timer like this:

```
timedTimer = new Timer();
    timedTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            TimedMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
```

Where the interval is 1000 MS and the method TimedMethod() is called on every tick. How would I go about implementing a similar function in IOS?

Thanks so much for reading! Any help at all would be great! :-)

Answer (score 43):

You can use a repeating [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) like so:

```
- (void) startTimer {
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(tick:) 
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];
}

- (void) tick:(NSTimer *) timer {
   //do something here..

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In the same class as you called the above method, create a method called `timerCallback`. This will be called every time your timer fires; every 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method present in NSTimer.h file of Foundation Framework

Syntax :

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

Usage :

```
#define kSyncTimerLength 4 //Declare globally
-(void) timerActivityFunction; //Declare in interface

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kSyncTimerLength target:self
        selector:@selector(timerActivityFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) timerActivityFunction {
     // perform timer task over-here   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift:**

Create a timer object using below line which will call upload method every 10 second. If you get **does not implement methodSignatureForSelector** extend your class with NSObject. Read this for more information [Object X of class Y does not implement methodSignatureForSelector in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415662/object-x-of-class-y-does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-in-swift)

```
 timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: "upload", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func upload() {
        print("hi")
    }
```