# Object X of class Y does not implement methodSignatureForSelector in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a class Person which is instantiated multiple times.Each person get's their own timer. Upon in my `init` for `Person` I call `startTimer()`.

```
class Person {
 var timer = NSTimer()
 func startTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

 func timerTick() {
    angerLevel++
    println("Angry! \(angerLevel)")
 }
...
...
}
```

So I may have 3 instances of Person in an array of `Person[]`. I am getting an error:

```
2014-06-25 13:57:14.956 ThisProgram[3842:148856] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x113760048 of class '_TtC11ThisProgram6Person' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
```

I read elsewhere that I should inherit from `NSObject` but this is in Swift not Obj-C. The function is within the class so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You already figured out that the class should inherit from NSObject: `class Person : NSObject { ... }`. Are you looking for a different solution?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Don't think of `NSObject` as an Objective-C class, think of it as a Cocoa/Foundation class. Even though you're using Swift instead of Objective-C, you're still using all the same frameworks.

Two options: (1) add the `dynamic` attribute to the function you want to reference as a selector:

```
    dynamic func timerTick() {
        self.angerLevel++
        print("Angry! \(self.angerLevel)")
    }
```

Or (2) declare `Person` as a subclass of `NSObject`, then just call `super.init()` at the beginning of your initializer:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var angerLevel = 0

    func startTimer() {
        print("starting timer")
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerTick", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func timerTick() {
        self.angerLevel++
        print("Angry! \(self.angerLevel)")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.startTimer()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also be able to decorate the function declaration like this `@objc func timerTick()`. The NSTimer API seems to be pretty dependent on the Obj-C Runtime.

Comment: Good call - added to the answer

Comment: Thanks this FIXED my issue. But can you explain why? What does it need the @objc part?

Comment: `NSTimer` uses message forwarding to call the targeted selector, which is an Objective-C feature not handled on Swift types by default. When you use the `@objc` attribute or inherit from an Objective-C class, you're opting into several features, include message forwarding.

Comment: Neither of these solutions is needed any longer. It is sufficient to declare the selector function `dynamic`. They are both good and they both still work, but using `dynamic` on this one function may be seen a more lightweight approach.

Answer (score 32):

Since XCode6 beta 6, you can use 'dynamic' func

```
dynamic func timerTick() { .... }
```

Comment: this solved my problem trying to use UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()

Comment: This is a better approach vs making the entire class inherit from NSObject.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error trying to use
`let encodedArchive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(archive) as NSData` where archive was an array of a custom class. I found that declaring that custom class as a subclass of NSObject and NSCoding did the trick. It'll require a few more lines to conform to the protocol of NSCoding so it'll look something like this to start with:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
  init() {
    super.init()
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(_aCoder: NSCoder) {   }
}
```