# Swift: UITapGestureRecognizer for uiimageview terminate app in custome view

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have some Class extended from base class (`MSC_CLItem`) like this:

```
class MSC_CLItem
{
    var Type:MSC_CustomListType!

    func RenderUI(Point:CGPoint) -> UIView
    {
        return UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
}
```

Each extended class must to override `RenderUI func` to generate itself. All of the extended objects will be added in UIScrollView. Now my problem is: 
An uiimageview with TapGesture inside of custom view not detect action. For example my class is:

```
class MSC_CLItem_Tizer : MSC_CLItem
{
    var Title:String!
    var Video:MSC_CLItem_TizerVideo!
    var Detail:MSC_CLItem_TizerDetail!

    private init(title:String!)
    {
        super.init()
        self.Title = title
        super.Type = .Tizer
    }

    override func RenderUI(Point:CGPoint) -> UIView
    {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        v.frame.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width - 10, height: CGFloat(160))
        v.frame.origin = Point

        let vid = UIImageView()
        vid.image = UIImage(named: "default")
        vid.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        vid.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        vid.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "Image HTTP url")!)
        vid.frame.size = v.frame.size
        vid.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        vid.clipsToBounds = true
        vid.userInteractionEnabled = true
        v.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped:"))
        vid.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        v.addSubview(vid)
    }

    func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //Not detected to here
    }
}
```

And when I tap on image the following error occurred:

**NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7c8cc830 of class 'MSC_CLItem_Tizer' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[MSC_CLItem_Tizer imageTapped:]**

I'm very confused of which section of my code is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must declare the super class as NSObject**

```
class MSC_CLItem : NSObject
{
  ......
}


let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped:"))
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
vid.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
v.addSubview(vid)
self.view.addSubview(v)
```

For more details

[Does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: — trouble ahead](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-trouble-ahead/)

[Got Unrecognized selector -replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver: crash when implementing NSCoding in Swift [Xcode 6 GM]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805599/got-unrecognized-selector-replacementobjectforkeyedarchiver-crash-when-impleme)

Comment: Tnx for solution, I try your solution and many other but have same error

Comment: is imageTapped method calling first?

Comment: Why did you set two images for gesture recognizer?

Comment: One of them is local and second is remote (HTTP)

Comment: very useful but not exactly correct, I cant's extend from 2 class in my class, so I extend MSC_CLItem from NSObject and worked fine, Please correct your answer to help others.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I guess here can be a problem. Write this line without ":"

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped"))
```