# NSNotification cannot find selector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, unrecognized-selector, nsnotification

I'm posting a notification via the default center, like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(ColorDidGetTappedNotification, object: self)
```

I'm observing the notification in another instance like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("colorDidGetTapped:"), name: ColorDidGetTappedNotification, object: nil)
....
func colorDidGetTapped(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Notification recieved")
}
```

But I get an unrecognized selector exception:

**UPDATE 1**

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7d564490 of class '_D.GameModel' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[_D.GameModel colorDidGetTapped:]
```

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: Your  `GameModel` class must inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415662/object-x-of-class-y-does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-in-swift.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I don't think you're supposed to go around editing people's questions like that, especially the code!

Answer (score 5):

Check GameModel is NSObject's subclass

```
class GameModel: NSObject {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to observe the Notification using this method: `addObserverForName(_:object:queue:usingBlock:)`. Instead of a selector you pass a block