# UIButton click crashing does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift when the button is pressed the App crashes with error

> does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector

In the code a Controller class of mine gets a reference to a UIButton and adds a target like the following

```
aButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

The function pressed is defined as

```
func pressed(sender:UIButton)
{
   println("button pressed")
}
```

Controller class is defined like

```
class MyController
{
 init()
{
}
// Also here it gets the reference to the UIButton and has pressed function as well.
}
```

Comment: Very similar Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415662/object-x-of-class-y-does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-in-swift.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem as I discovered was that MyController class need to inherit from NSObject class. Changing the class declaration to as following fixed my problem.

```
class MyController : NSObject
{
    override init() // since it is overriding the NSObject init
    {
    }
}
```

This is probably because NSObject implements methods like `respondsToSelector`. And before calling the pressed: function it tries to check if it infact implements the selector pressed:. But since MyController doesn't have `respondsToSelector` either, so it crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to add `@objc` to your `class` declaration.

I have found that using `NSTimer` invocations crash otherwise.

Comment: adding @objc right before the function the button calls worked me.