# NSTimer in singleton is not working

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, nstimer

I would like to use a singleton to manage a NSTimer.
This singleton should start/stop a timer and this timer should run a function each time the timer is done.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class TimerManager{

    var delegate: TimerManager?
    var timer: NSTimer?

    static let sharedInstance = TimerManager()

    private init(){
        timer = NSTimer()
    }

    func startTimer(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("countUp"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func countUp(){
        print("do something...")
    }

}
```

But this is makes an error

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fa04a42c840 of class 'Ttc.TimerManager' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[Ttc.TrackingManager countUp]

Comment: if TimerManager is a singleton, shouldn't it be `static let sharedInstance = TimerManager()` instead of `TrackingManager`?

Comment: Once you instantiate it the class functions are effectively invisible.

Comment: I edited my code. TrackingManager my old Class name. I also remove Class before countUp function but I still have the same error.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415662/object-x-of-class-y-does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-in-swift

Comment: thanks @Nimble. I add @ objc before func countUp() and it works... I suppose it is because NSTimer inherits from NSObject