# UIBarbuttonItem action not working at all

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a following helper class

```
class PDFPreviewHelper {
    var pdfNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    func previewButtonPressed(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        let pdfViewController = PDFViewController(resource: "final.pdf")
        pdfNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pdfViewController)

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF")
        pdfViewController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, animated: false)

        rootViewController.presentViewController(pdfNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    func backButtonPressedInPDF() {
        pdfNavigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I call a function in above helper class in my rootviewcontroller like following:

```
func previewInPdfButtonPressed() {
    let a = PDFPreviewHelper()
    a.viewI129InPDF(self)
}
```

I successfully modally present `pdfNavigationController` on top of my `rootViewController`, but whenever i press `back` button, nothing gets called. Why is this so? I set a break point in `backButtonPressedInPDF` function and it doesn't even hit the break point.

Comment: are you sure you are calling `a.viewI129InPDF(self)`

Comment: @Johnykutty, yes it does modally show PDFViewController.

Comment: but in your `PDFPreviewHelper`  you wrote `previewButtonPressed` as the method

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF")
```

To:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF:")
```

I believe the problem as at `action: "backButtonPressedInPDF"` where there is a missing `:`

In addition, change your method by adding `(sender:AnyObject)` also?

```
func backButtonPressedInPDF(sender:AnyObject) {
        pdfNavigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `leftBarButtonItem` to `UINavigationController` via below way.

```
pdfViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF")
```

Comment: That's same as what I did.

Comment: @Kahsn Please check your's you have done in a different way!

Comment: Why are actions in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are creating a temporary instance of `PDFPreviewHelper` class and using it to present the view controller. Not keeping the reference. 
This can be fixed in two ways:

**Method 1:** Add `previewInPdfButtonPressed` method to your `PDFViewController` class. Then change implementation like following.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: pdfViewController, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF")
```

**Method 2:**
You should keep the object `a` until you dismiss your `PDFViewController-navigationcontroller`.
Even if you do like this you will get an exception like

```
2016-03-16 15:43:03.140 XXXX[3757:585277] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7ff5eb72be70 of class 'XXXX.PDFPreviewHelper' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[XXXX.PDFPreviewHelper backButtonPressedInPDF]
```

This is because you are not subclassing `NSObject` for your `PDFPreviewHelper`.
You can fix it in two ways,

1. Make `PDFPreviewHelper` as `NSObject` subclass.
2. Add `dynamic`
   keyword to the function like  `dynamic func previewInPdfButtonPressed() {....}`.

[Resolution to this issue is well described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415662/object-x-of-class-y-does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
func previewInPdfButtonPressed() 
{
    let a = PDFPreviewHelper()
    a.viewI129InPDF(self)
}
```

The problem is `a` is released when the program goes out of the scope of this function. The action you target on `a` of course can't be executed anymore

**solution** add `a` as a property of the `viewController`